# how to parse array of objects inside an object using maps or forEach

Tags: javascript, json, foreach, javascript-objects

my JSON data looks like this: `{
            "objects": [
                {
                    "name": "case1",
                    "description": "description of case1",
                    "shapes": [
                        {
                            "shape_name": "circle"
                        }
                    ],
                    "order_ref": [
                        {
                            "id": "2233"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "name": "case2",
                    "description": "description of case2",
                    "shapes": [
                        {
                            "shape_name": "heart"
                        },
                        {
                            "shape_name": "square"
                        }
                    ],
                    "order_ref": [
                        {
                            "id": "1212"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ]
        }`

I need to create a table from the data.
The table should look like this:

```
Id      Shape      Name    Description
2233   Circle      Case1   Desc of case1
1212   Heart       Case2   Desc of case2
1212   Square      Case2    Desc of case2
```

I tried to parse JSON data using maps: I am able to get name and description but cannot go inside shapes and order_ref. Can you suggest me a solution using maps or forEach

Comment: basically you just have to do the same thing but one level down.. maybe post the code that you have done to get the name and description

Comment: What you have done so far? where is that you need help?

Answer (score 0):

You can do forEach within a forEach, ex:

```
let array = [
                {
                    name: "case1",
                    description: "description of case1",
                    shapes: [
                        {
                            shape_name: "circle"
                        }
                    ],
                    order_ref: [
                        {
                            id: "2233"
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    name: "case2",
                    description: "description of case2",
                    shapes: [
                        {
                            shape_name: "heart"
                        },
                        {
                            shape_name: "square"
                        }
                    ],
                    order_ref: [
                        {
                            id: "1212"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ];

let newArray = [];

array.forEach(obj => {
  obj.shapes.forEach(shape => {
    let newObj = Object.assign({}, obj);
    newObj.shape_name = shape.shape_name;
    delete newObj.shapes;
    newObj.id = obj.order_ref[0].id;
    delete newObj.order_ref;
    newArray.push(newObj);
  });
});

console.log(newArray);
```

After you are getting the newArray, you can iterate it with  and  as per normal

Answer (score 0):

You need two `forEach()` to achieve the table.

You can try the following way

```js
var data = {
  "objects": [
      {
          "name": "case1",
          "description": "description of case1",
          "shapes": [
              {
                  "shape_name": "circle"
              }
          ],
          "order_ref": [
              {
                  "id": "2233"
              }
          ]
      },
      {
          "name": "case2",
          "description": "description of case2",
          "shapes": [
              {
                  "shape_name": "heart"
              },
              {
                  "shape_name": "square"
              }
          ],
          "order_ref": [
              {
                  "id": "1212"
              }
          ]
      }
  ]
}
 var tr = '';
data.objects.forEach(o => {
  o.shapes.forEach(io => {
    tr += `<tr><td>${o.order_ref[0].id}</td><td>${io.shape_name}</td><td>${o.name}</td><td>${o.description}</td></tr>`;
  });
});
document.querySelector('#tableData tbody').insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', tr);
```

```css
table, th, td {
  border: 1px solid black;
}
td:first-letter{
  text-transform: capitalize
}
```

```html
<table id="tableData">
  <thead>
    <th>Id</th>
    <th>Shape</th>
    <th>Name</th>
    <th>Description</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody></tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need an entry for every order ref id and shape, you can use forEach as per below:

```
let jsonArray = {
    "objects": [
        {
            "name": "case1",
            "description": "description of case1",
            "shapes": [
                {
                    "shape_name": "circle"
                }
            ],
            "order_ref": [
                {
                    "id": "2233"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "case2",
            "description": "description of case2",
            "shapes": [
                {
                    "shape_name": "heart"
                },
                {
                    "shape_name": "square"
                }
            ],
            "order_ref": [
                {
                    "id": "1212"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}

let output = [];
jsonArray.objects.forEach(object => {
    object.order_ref.forEach(order => {
        object.shapes.forEach(shape => {
            output.push({
                id: order.id,
                shape: shape.shape_name,
                name: object.name,
                description: object.description
            })
        })
    })
})
```